# Finding a function corresponding to the complex power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

The power series is:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 z^n$$

to which I have to find the function $f(z)$.

Taking the derivative or integrating did not get me anywhere in making it look like a geometric series.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Consider the map $g(z) \mapsto z\cdot g'(z)$. What does that do to a convergent power series about $0$?

Comment: sorry I don't follow you

Comment: If $$g(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n z^n,$$ then what is $z\cdot g'(z)$?

Comment: it's equal to $ng(z)$

Comment: That's if $a_n = n^2$. I'm looking at a generic power series. The goal is to reach your $f$ from a known function through that operation.

Comment: then it is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n z^n$

Comment: Right. Now, from what power series do we reach $\sum n^2 z^n$ with this operation?

Comment: so that power series is $\sum n z^n$. if we let $g = \sum n z^n$, then $zg'(z) = \sum n^2 z^n$ and the function corresponding to g(I have found before) is $z/(1-z)^2$. so whats left is to take the derivative of this function nd multiply by z

Comment: is that okay..?

Comment: Yes. Differentiating may be more convenient using $\dfrac{z}{(1-z)^2} = \dfrac{1 - (1-z)}{(1-z)^2} = \dfrac{1}{(1-z)^2} - \dfrac{1}{1-z}$.

Comment: got it, thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$
\dfrac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n \quad \forall |z|<1,
$$
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2z^n&=&z\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2z^{n-1}=z\dfrac{d}{dz}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n\right)=z\dfrac{d}{dz}\left(z\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1}\right)=z\dfrac{d}{dz}\left[z\dfrac{d}{dz}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\right)\right]\\
&=&z\dfrac{d}{dz}\left[z\dfrac{d}{dz}\left(\dfrac{1}{1-z}\right)\right]=z\dfrac{d}{dz}\left[\dfrac{z}{(z-1)^2}\right]=z\dfrac{(z-1)^2-2z(z-1)}{(z-1)^4}\\
&=&z\dfrac{z-1-2z}{(z-1)^3}=\dfrac{z(1+z)}{(1-z)^3}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n =\frac{1}{1-z}
\end{eqnarray*}
Differentiate this & we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n z^{n-1} =\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Diffentiate again 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{n(n-1)}{2}z^{n-2} =\frac{1}{(1-z)^3}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now shift the sum index by one
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n(n+1)}{2}z^{n-2} =\frac{z}{(1-z)^3}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiply the second to last equation by $z^2$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n(n+1)}{2}z^{n} =\frac{z^2}{(1-z)^3}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Now add the previous two equations and shift the index by 1
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2 z^{n} =\frac{z(1+z)}{(1-z)^3}
\end{eqnarray*}