# Find a function for the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{3n+1}}{3n+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I have to find the function for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{3n+1}}{3n+1}$

I found on [Finding a function corresponding to the complex power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150495/finding-a-function-corresponding-to-the-complex-power-series) that I could uset the fact that  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z} \ \forall |z| < 1$. But if I make the substitution $m = 3n + 1$,  I get $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{z^m}{m}$. Because now the sum goes from $1$ to $\infty$ and not from $0$, as far as I know, I cannot use the formula for the geometric series. Am I wrong about my assumption or do I have to determine it some other way?

Comment: Your substitution is not quite correct: your summation would imply that all $m$ would be of the form $3n+1$, when it's not the case for, say, $2$. Hint: what operations can you do on your power series? Try to think of one that'd make you go back to the geometric series.

Comment: You should look up the Taylor expansion of the natural logarithm, series multisection and roots of unity.

Comment: @AndrewKovács I don't think He needs to use such tricks like series multisection. It rather looks like a sum-integral permutation trick.

Comment: @BrunoB thanks for the remark! I didn't see the mistake at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{z^{3n+1}}{3n+1}=\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty\int_0^z\!\!x^{3n}\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^z\!\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty x^{3n}\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^z\!\!\!\dfrac1{1-x^3}\,\mathrm dx$

Can you calculate the last definite integral ?

Note that

$\dfrac1{1-x^3}=\dfrac13\!\cdot\!\dfrac1{1-x}+\dfrac16\!\cdot\!\dfrac{1+2x}{1+x+x^2}+\dfrac12\!\cdot\!\dfrac1{\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}\;.$

Moreover ,

$\displaystyle\int_0^z\dfrac1{1-x}\,\mathrm dx=\big[-\ln(1-x)\big]_0^z=-\ln(1-z)\;\;,$

$\displaystyle\int_0^z\dfrac{1+2x}{1+x+x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\big[\ln\left(1+x+x^2\right)\big]_0^z=\ln\left(1+z+z^2\right)\;\;,$

$\displaystyle\int_0^z\dfrac1{\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}\,\mathrm dx=\left[\dfrac2{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\dfrac{2x+1}{\sqrt3}\right)\right]_0^z=$

$\qquad=\dfrac2{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\dfrac{2z+1}{\sqrt3}\right)-\dfrac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}\;\;.$

Comment: It should be a definite integral, $\int_0^z\frac{1}{1-t^3}\mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: Sure, indeed it is a definite integral.

Comment: @Angelo thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Denote
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{3n+1}}{3n+1}.
$$
Now you can differentiate the series and obtain
$$
f'(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{3n} = \frac{1}{1 - z^3}.
$$
After this you can find $f(z_0)$ at any point $z_0$ by integrating and using the fact that $f(0) = 0$
$$
f(z_0) = \int_{0}^{z_0} f'(z) \, dz.
$$